# Touching on wedding day?

Tags: wedding, niddah

If the woman has gone to the mikva already and is not a niddah, can the groom and bride touch on the day of the wedding?

For example, pictures before the chuppa or another shaas hadchak.

Comment: Can you explain why this is different from any other man touching any other non-nidda on any other day?

Comment: The minhag is to not touch a non-nidda. Curious if this changes in a shaas hadchak and if wedding pictures are classified as such.

Comment: If you can cite the existence of a particular Minhag you can more meaningfully ask about changes to it in particular circumstances. I don't know what Minhag you're talking about.